# What's the best way to use a custom field to modify the CSS of a Wordpress template?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am modifying a WordPress template and haven't done so in about 5 years.

I want to be able to change the background color of posts by inputing a color value in a custom field in the Wordpress back end. Specifically I want to be able to have multiple background colors for different posts, I don't want the latest post to determine the background color of the entire site.

For example, I might enter "CCCCCC" to specify that the page background for that particular post be grey.

I can see how to use the post_meta function (and others) to print that information into the HTML, but can't see an elegant way to use that to modify the CSS.

How would you suggest that's done?

One challenge is that the custom value is called from the loop. If I want to change the color of the entire page it's better to change the background color of the body, but that would need to happen in the header.

I'd really like to avoid JS. Is there a light, smart way of doing this?

Obviously this is how a value can be passed to the page. However I want to modify the CSS.

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Background color', true );
    // Check if the custom field has a value.
    if ( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) { 
        echo $key_1_value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just need to change the css based on the variable, am I correct? So you could use inline-style css, for example

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Background color', true );
$key_1_value =  (!empty( $key_1_value )) ? $key_1_value : 'white';
     
<div style="background-color: <?php echo $key_1_value ;?>"></div>
```

Comment: This looks elegant and works. I actually tried this before posting here but I must have messed up the syntax. I am so... rusty. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you haven't done CSS in 5 years, or just WordPress theming in general, but my recommendation would be to use CSS variables (custom properties). The CSS function `var()` accepts a fallback value as the second parameter, do use that as your default and then give the variable a meaningful name that you can optionally set later.

```html
<style>
.body-copy {
  color: var(--body-copy-color, #000);
}
</style>
<div class="body-copy">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vitae lectus neque. Duis non sagittis dolor. Nunc tincidunt consectetur nunc, nec tristique turpis tempus ut. Ut sit amet enim sapien. Aliquam rutrum tellus tellus, ac aliquet nisl efficitur sollicitudin. Suspendisse varius eget justo at porta. Cras maximus quam dui, ac fringilla est pharetra ut.
</div>
<div class="body-copy" style="--body-copy-color: #f00;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vitae lectus neque. Duis non sagittis dolor. Nunc tincidunt consectetur nunc, nec tristique turpis tempus ut. Ut sit amet enim sapien. Aliquam rutrum tellus tellus, ac aliquet nisl efficitur sollicitudin. Suspendisse varius eget justo at porta. Cras maximus quam dui, ac fringilla est pharetra ut.
</div>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/ExdExvR

Comment: Thanks - this is great and works. Given that it involves an extra function vs. the solution below https://stackoverflow.com/a/76204131/1981239 - is there an advantage in this approach? Both account for the variable being unspecified.

Comment: The biggest is specificity. The only way to override an inline style is with `!important`. By using the variable inline the variable becomes more specific, but the `.body-copy{...}` declaration's specificity [isn't affected](https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/ExdExvR). This may or may not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress already injects the tag and categories into the  `<article>` block for your articles.

```
<article id="post-555" class="posts-entry fbox post-555 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-open-source">
```

So you could give a special tag to the articles you want to have different background colors without any need to change any wordpress/php code.

Comment: That's good information but would require me to edit the CSS each time. I want to be able to specify the color code from the WP back end.

Comment: Why would it require you to edit the CSS each time? Just pick a bunch of colors you like, create a tag for each one, and dump them in the custom css.

Comment: That said it looks like the other response covers your use case nicely.